# Django Wsgi Error "Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process"

Tags: django, wsgi

I've got this issue that was described elsewhere:

[Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829085/truncated-or-oversized-response-headers-received-from-daemon-process)

But the solution of inserting buffer-size-=32768 into httpd.conf doesn't seem to solve it - and I don't have the knowledge to reinstall everything from scratch as the wsgi forum suggests (plus this question doesn't seem properly solved on stackoverflow).

I'm essentially trying to upload 1-5mb files through an upload button using django and process the data using python and fortran (f2py).  At some point - pretty randomly - I get this error which appear right when going into/out of the fortran routine.  The error seems to move around to different forms - no idea why.  And presumably the data arrays that are passed back and forth are a bit large (though probably <5mb altogether at the most).

```
[Fri Feb 05 07:33:20.982688 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 25197:tid 140397979866880] Into fortran... 
[Fri Feb 05 07:33:21.013889 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 25198:tid 140397984610048] [client 127.0.0.1:49604] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'my_django_app': /home/catubc/webapps/my_django_app/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py, referer: http://www.spikesortingtest.com/upload/ 
[Fri Feb 05 07:33:21.964241 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2545:tid 140398148085632] AH00052: child pid 25197 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I've been chasing my tail for past couple of days, any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,
catubc