# Django Apache2 VirtualEnv - no response from server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

So I am trying to migrate my app to a new production server. I'm not getting a reply from the server Apache server when I access it. The server is on AWS and it's a standard Apache config with just one site enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/static
    Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/media

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp python-path=/home/ubuntu/myapp:/home/ubuntu/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myapp_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have made sure that all files are owned by the ubuntu user and that www-data has group rights.

The wsgi file is the original, but I added a print statement to see the folder it's checking for the application:

```
"""
WSGI config for match2 project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys

print(sys.path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Eventually, the error log will produce:

```
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'myapp': /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
```

I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

`Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'myapp'` means your application is taking to long to handle the request. This could be because it is deadlocked, or is waiting on backend service.

Add `WSGIApplicationGroup` to your virtual host configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # config remaining parts
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    # config remaining parts
</VirtualHost>
```

From [docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#daemon-mode-single-application)

> ... forces the WSGI application to run in the main Python interpreter context of each process. This is preferred in this scenario as some third party packages for Python which include C extensions will not run in the Python sub interpreter contexts which mod_wsgi would use by default. By using the main Python interpreter context you eliminate the possibility of such third party packages for Python causing problems.

A similar case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40413171/13317858).

Also:
Looking at this,

```
python-home=/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/myapp python-path=/home/ubuntu/myapp:/home/ubuntu/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I think you have the wrong path for `python-home`. Make sure `python-home` path is correctly provided. Activate your virtual environment and run the command to get the `python-home` path [[docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html?highlight=python-home#location-of-the-virtual-environment)].

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'
```